# How to get test coverage from code until a node_module using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, node-modules

I use Jest to write and run units tests. I want to get test coverage reports from source code files, these files are in a `node_modules` directory, but these files are completely ignored.

Why would I do it? Because it is using AWS SAM, and I have different lambda layers under the project root directory, so I have multiple `node_modules` subdirectories, too.

I tried to override this setting with the Jest's `forceCoverageMatch` option and to exclude specific files with`transformIgnorePatterns`. I read several issues on GitHub (https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2145, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5046, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5039).

In `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --ci --passWithNoTests --config ./jest.config.js"
}

...

"devDependencies": {
  "jest": "^24.8.0",
  "jest-junit": "6.4.0"
}
```

In `jest.config.js`:

```
 module.exports = {
 verbose: true,
 clearMocks: true,
 collectCoverage: true,
 coverageReporters: ['html', 'cobertura'],
 collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{js,jsx}',
 ],
 reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
 moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx']
 moduleNameMapper: { '^/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/*/$1' }
}
```

I expect that every `.js` file should be included in the test coverage. And every test are included, except the ones under a `node_modulse` subdirectory.